# Custom formatting coordinate grid using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, labeling, grids-graticules

I am custom formatting my coordinate grid.

Is there a way to change the following formula so that the output comes with a decimal and suffix?

```
substr(@grid_number, length(@grid_number) -6,5)
```

The following provides a suffix, but again I need this to be with less digits like above and a decimal:

```
abs(@grid_number ) 
|| ' °' 
|| CASE 
    WHEN  @grid_axis = 'x' 
       THEN 
         IF (@grid_number > 0, 'E' , 'W')
       ELSE
           IF (@grid_number > 0, 'N' , 'S')
       END
```

Perhaps there is a way to combine the two so that I can achieve a coordinate format like the following:

19.53'2°N

Comment: use the `round()` function if you want a number with fewer digits. If the number is stored as a string you might need to use the `to_real` function to convert it to a number.

Comment: are you sure you want minutes before degrees? that's a very confusing format.

Comment: @csk this question looks ripe for an answer based on your comments